# Representing the Results of Panel with Three Dimensions

Tags: econometrics, r

I have a panel with three dimensions: country, industry and year. For each country within my sample (c = 30), I am running a two-way fixed-effects model, where I add dummies for each year (t-1) and industry (i-1) apart from 1 to avoid problems of multi-collinearity.

I now have 30 regression models and would like to report these results in a table. The standard way of adding a model in each column in this case would be problematic. I could also try to flip the table and add model for each row.

Could someone please advise how this could be done efficiently? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using graphs.

Pick a benchmark country depending on your study and show its results in a table.

Pick parameters that are most pertinent to your research.

Then make graph of those point estimates.

Depending on what you are showing, you could use different graphs.

For example, if you have two parameters important to your study, you could make a scatterplot involving the parameters with label equal to country. Maybe specifically highlight your benchmark country.

The point of tables and graphs is to tell a convincing and scientific story about your work so that the reader knows exactly what you are trying to say. Keeping that in mind try different R graphs.

Comment: Hey Erik, thanks for your answer! Could you please share a link that describes the graphs you are referring to?